# Files.probeContentType(Path) does return NULL for any file

Tags: java, java-8, nio, aix, j9

When determining the content type of a file with `Files.probeFileContent(Path)` for each file the result is `null`.

Environment:

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6480sr1fp1-20150603_01(SR1 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 AIX ppc64-64 Compressed References 20150410_243669 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_Java8_SR1_20150410_1531_B243669
JIT  - tr.r14.java_20150402_88976.03
GC   - R28_Java8_SR1_20150410_1531_B243669_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20150410_243669)
JCL - 20150601_01 based on Oracle jdk8u45-b13
```

Comment: FYI: `probeFileContent` is a wrong method name.

Comment: Well, most likely, there are no `FileTypeDetector`s installed. That’s the standard situation. There’s a Windows Registry based fallback in openJDK, but you are not using Windows…

Comment: @MaximDobryakov Thanks for editing!

Comment: @Holger Is there any recommended `FileTypeDetector`s?

Comment: I’d also have to google…